# Generating code coverage and reports for all modules using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jacoco, android-instant-apps

We have an instant app project that is instrumented using jacaco. We run these jobs and report on the coverage using the jenkins coverage reporting plugin.

Our reports only show coverage reports for the base module and not the feature modules.

How do we resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the ***jacoco plugin*** for ***Jenkins*** I realized I needed to add the other modules details to the various fields:

---

Path to exec files (e.g.: **/target/**.exec, **/jacoco.exec):

*Example:*

```
base/build/jacoco/*.exec, feature-1/build/jacoco/*.exec
```

---

Path to class directories (e.g.: **/target/classDir, **/classes)

*Example:*

```
base/build/intermediates/classes/debug, feature-1/build/intermediates/classes/debug
```